# Laravel dusk (PhpUnit) failing to test login

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-dusk

I am creating browsers testnexample from https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk and the tests keeps failing. I can see the browser open typing but on trying to authenticate its unable to authenticate credentials.

I have the .env.dusk.local setup with two different DBs but still not working.

I have seen a lot of people with similar problem but no one has got an answer to solve the problem like [Set up Laravel 5.4 with Dusk using phpunit.xml, .env.dusk.local, and an sqlite in-memory database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908118/set-up-laravel-5-4-with-dusk-using-phpunit-xml-env-dusk-local-and-an-sqlite-i)

```
namespace Tests\Browser;

use emad\User;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class AuthBroswerTest extends DuskTestCase
{

    use DatabaseMigrations;

/** @test **/
public function user_can_login()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'email' => 'test@example.com'
    ]);

    $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($user) {
        $browser->visit('/login')
            ->type('email', $user->email)
            ->type('password', '1qazwsx')
            ->press('login')
            ->assertPathIs('/');
    });

}

}
```

Comment: Erick, you are forcing the password. The User migration is creating the exact password as you passing on your dusk test?

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create([
    'email' => 'test@example.com',
    'password' => bcrypt('1qazwsx')
]);
```

You created a user but you didn't set a password.
Hence the issue.